# Set of possible reflections of a vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection

How many vectors can one construct by by reflecting a vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^d$ for $b\neq 0$?

Reflections can be described by Householder matrices $H=I-2vv^T/||v||_2^2$.

In other words, I'm interested in the subset $S(b):=\{v\mid \exists \text{ Householder Matrix } H: v=Hb\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$.

Is it true that $S(b)=\{ v \mid ||v||_2^2=||b||_2^2\}$?

Comment: Did you mean $I - 2\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2}$? According to my calculations, $I - \frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2}$ is an (orthogonal) projection.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I updated the question to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Every reflection of $b$ has the same norm, as $H$ is orthogonal. Specifically,
\begin{align*}
H^\top H &= \left(I - 2\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2}\right)^\top \left(I - 2\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2}\right) \\
&= \left(I - 2\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2}\right) \left(I - 2\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2}\right) \\
&= I - 4\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2} + 4\frac{v(v^\top v) v^\top}{\|v\|^4} \\
&= I - 4\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2} + 4\frac{v v^\top}{\|v\|^2} \\
&= I = HH^\top.
\end{align*}
Therefore $\|Hb\| = \|b\|$ for all such matrices $H$.

On the other hand, choose any $c$ such that $\|c\| = \|b\|$, and let $v = b - c$. I claim that the $H$ corresponding to $v$ maps $b$ to $c$. We have
\begin{align*}
Hb - c &= \left(I - 2\frac{vv^\top}{\|v\|^2}\right)b - c \\
&= b - 2\frac{vv^\top b}{\|v\|^2} - c \\
&= b - c - 2(v \cdot b) \frac{v}{\|v\|^2} \\
&= b - c - 2((b - c) \cdot b) \frac{(b - c)}{\|b - c\|^2} \\
&= ((b - c) \cdot (b - c) - 2(b - c) \cdot b)\frac{b - c}{\|b - c\|^2} \\
&= ((b - c) \cdot (-b - c))\frac{b - c}{\|b - c\|^2} \\
&= (c \cdot c - b \cdot b)\frac{b - c}{\|b - c\|^2} \\
&= (\|c\|^2 - \|b\|^2)\frac{b - c}{\|b - c\|^2} \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: In equality 3, it seems the equality says that $vv^Tb=(v\cdot b)v$? I understand the right hand side, $vv^Tb\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, this is a vector. That said, I do not understand the left hand side, $(v \cdot b)v$. How is this also a vector? Maybe, did you mean to write $vb^Tv$?

Comment: @AlexanderMathiasen The dot product is scalar-valued, so $(v \cdot b)v$ is the product of a scalar and a vector, which is a vector. Indeed, $v^\top b$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, whose only entry is $v \cdot b$, and so multiplying the $d \times 1$ vector $v$ to $v^\top b$ is the same thing as scaling $v$ by $v \cdot b$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I don't know why, but I read $\cdot$ as entry-wise product. If $\cdot$ denotes dot-product, I could've also written $(v\cdot b)v$ as $v^Tbv$, right?

Comment: @AlexanderMathiasen Yes... sort of. As a matrix product, $v^\top b v$ doesn't make sense, since the product $bv$ doesn't line up in terms of dimensions. It would be better to write it as $(v^\top b)v$; we are abusing notation by using the $1 \times 1$ matrix $v^\top b$ as a scalar, and putting the product in parentheses seems slightly better.